# How to extract label value to a variable in Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In my Grafana I have a Variable:

Name: `variable_host_ip`

Type: `Query`

Data Source: `Prometheus`

Refresh: `On Dashboard Load`

Query: `query_result(kube_pod_info{pod=~".*kube-proxy.*"})`

Result:

```
kube_pod_info{created_by_kind="DaemonSet",created_by_name="kube-proxy",endpoint="kube-state-metrics",host_ip="192.168.0.238",instance="192.168.0.244:8080",job="kube-state",namespace="kube-system",node="192.168.0.2",pod="kube-proxy-",pod_ip="192.168.0.123",service="kube-prometheus-exporter"}
```

How can I filter this so the result will be `192.168.0.238`?

I tried with regex but Grafana doesn't seem to support advanced regex to extract IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following Regex:

```
/.*host_ip="([^"]+)".*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `label_values(EXPRESSION, LABEL)` as Query in the variable definition.